# JS Lodash: Multidimensional array to object, with a twist

Tags: javascript, object, multidimensional-array, underscore.js, lodash

I start with multi-dimensional array like so:

```
[
    ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3', 'prop3'],
    ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4']
]
```

I need to transform this in an object like this one:

```
{ prop1: 'val1',
  prop2: 'val2',
  prop3: ['val3', 'val4']
}
```

---

Normally I could use `_.object(array[0], array[1])` to solve this but the presence of the duplicate key `prop3` complicates things quite a bit;

Actual `_.object` will set `prop3: 'val4'`, erasing `val3`

Anyone got an idea on how I could achieve the results presented above?

Thank you

Comment: Will there always be 2 items in the array or can there be more?

Comment: Are those duplicate property names always adjacent to each other? Can the values be arrays as well?

Comment: To answer both questions:
- There can be more than 1 duplicate per key
- And no they won't necessarily be adjacent in the array

---

PS: can't we put linebreaks at least in these commments? can't seem to format this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably do something like this, which would be easy enough to turn into an underscore mixin:

```
var arr = [
    ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3', 'prop3'],
    ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4']
],
    keys = arr[0],
    vals = arr[1],
    obj = {};

keys.forEach( function( name, index )
{
    if ( !Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, name) )
    {
        obj[name] = vals[index];
    }
    else
    {
        if ( obj[name] instanceof Array )
        {
            obj[name].push( vals[index] );
        }
        else
        {
            var val = obj[name];
            obj[name] = [val, vals[index]];
        }
    }
} );
```

[Example in a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/y6ttk/5/) (turned into a mixin)

[jsPerf comparison with underscore-based code.](http://jsperf.com/array-to-object-with-nested-array/3)

Comment: `!obj[name]` is insufficient. What if the `obj[name] = false` or any non truthy value

Comment: Also `typeof x == 'array'` is not a thing

Comment: FWIW, the other example using Underscore methods almost exclusively clocks in at 18442.733ms, while using only the _.each() method in my answer above takes 5.314ms. If I take that out and use keys.forEach() instead, it brings the time down to 0.118ms.

Point being, if you can avoid using a library, it's faster. :)

Comment: Dang, I forgot to throw the _.mixin() into the prep section... My bad... Still, native is faster (and *I believe* easier to understand). :)

Comment: Seems to be working great, thanks!
I'd rather have a quick/compact code similar to @megawac suggestions, but at least I better understand what's going on here (always had issues getting the reduce funcs :S) 

plus, looks like it's faster indeed

Comment: `obj[name].isArray` is not a thing. You want `Array.isArray(obj[name])`. Note: many of these features require ES5

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y6ttk/4/ reflects proper checking of an array as well as turning it into a mixin, if you'd rather write one line (and have to use this over and over again), @OlivierClément.

Answer (score 1):

Simply zipping the arrays and then using a custom reduce should do the trick. Should be pretty simple to adapt this if your data `arr` can contain more than 2 collections.

```
_.mixin({
   asArray: function(value) {//simple helper from https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/pull/1467
     if (value == null) return [];
     if (value.length === +value.length && !_.isString(value)) return _.toArray(value);
     return [value];
   }
});


var arr = [
    ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3', 'prop3'],
    ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4']
];
/* ... */
_.chain(arr)
 .zip()
 .reduce(function(memo, propKey) {
   if(_.has(memo, propKey[0])) { // property already in the object. Make array if necessary and insert item at end
       (memo[propKey[0]] = _.asArray(memo[propKey[0]])).push(propKey[1]); //push value into object
   }
   else {
      memo[propKey[0]] = propKey[1];
   }
   return memo;
}, {})
 .value();
```

Produces: `{"prop1":"val1","prop2":"val2","prop3":["val3","val4"]}`

The `asArray` can be easily replaced if you don't want to mixin. See previous revision.

Comment: @jacobroufa if you want to benchmark correct your implementation and make a jsperf example

Comment: Revised my post to reflect your suggested changes and add a jsperf example comparison.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer - as it is, doesn't seem to do the trick;

As is, it results in: 

    Object {prop1,prop2,prop3,prop3: undefined, val1,val2,val3,val4: undefined}


Without the zip: 

    Object {prop1: "prop2", val1: "val2"}

which isn't what I'm after either



---

I am not sure why the zip would be needed too, as it seems to just wrap my arrays into more arrays...?

Comment: Whoops, sorry I broke the code between revisions ;). I used `.zip` to group your array into sub arrays of the form `[key, value]` for easy processing.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness I wanted to mention this method:

http://lodash.com/docs#zipObject
- or (new) _.object()

> Creates an object composed from arrays of keys and values. Provide either a single two dimensional array, i.e. [[key1, value1], [key2, value2]] or two arrays, one of keys and one of corresponding values.
>
> Example

```
_.zipObject(['fred', 'barney'], [30, 40]);
// → { 'fred': 30, 'barney': 40 }
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't combine several values into an array for one key:

```
_.object(['key1', 'key2'], [1,2]);
// { key1: 1, key2: 2 }
_.object(['key1', 'key1'], [1,2]);
// { key1: 2 }
_.object(['key1'], [1,2]);
// { key1: 1 }
```

So this is not really the solution to your answer but I think it's still valuable to take note of this function.